# Design Pattern for CRUD operations on a list (saved to XML) using Spring MVC

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, spring-mvc, xml-parsing, crud

I'm trying to enhance an existing Java Web application using Spring MVC, XMLBeans and the usual Java EE stack. There are various lists (list of objects) on which the end user performs a CRUD operation. The list is ultimately saved to an XML file using XMLBeans. The updated list is again pulled back from XML file using XMLBeans and is displayed to the user. Is there a suitable design pattern to optimize these operations?

I'm planning to store a random ID for each item in the list to the XML and use it as a html form hidden field to identify which list element is currently modified for CRUD. Any better way to do it? Since the data is ultimately stored to an XML, there's no default ID (like in a database) so I'm thinking about randomly generating an ID and using that to track. Is there a design pattern that addresses this use case?

I'm also trying to figure out a way to track if a CRUD operation is successful. This way the end user can know if the request went through. Maybe a callback message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as pattern usage goes, I assume that your front end is decoupled from the nuts and bolts of the CRUD operations by using a nice POJO, DTO, etc (ref http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html).  This way, you can change to any other persistence mechanism in the future without affecting your client side.  Your MVC controller would then be serving up POJOs or some representation thereof, in the usual manner.

In regards to the ID creation, my opinion is not to use a random number, mainly because of the possibility of generating duplicate keys.  I personally tend to lean toward something more deterministic, e.g. a long count or a timestamp.  You did not mention the architecture of your back end, so there still may be a possibility to produce duplicate keys, but with a bit of care this could be minimized.

In regards to illustrating the success/failure of the operation to an end user, I am not sure there is enough information to give a clear answer.  It may depend on what the end user expects.  If the end user is a software consumer of the information, they would expect the set of IDs upon creation and a success indication upon update/delete.  If it is a living, breathing human then you would want to do a bit of interaction design here.  For example, if the user is *really* doing CRUD operations, then they may very well expect to see the generated IDs with the contents of the saved data; but if things are more abstract than this, perhaps a simple "success" message in the header/footer of your front end is sufficient from a visual perspective.  This may take the form of a callback technically (e.g. AJAX/jQuery) or it might simply be a JSP presenting the results, or a combination of both.

Comment: DAO pattern is currently in use. So I guess there's little room for improvement in that arena.. Regarding duplicate keys, I like your idea of a long counter. The challenge is that everything is stored into the  XML. So the long counter has to be stored in the xml as well which adds an extra thing to manage. But I don't see any better way. Regarding the "success" message, The end user is human. I can have the CRUD functions return a success message upon completion but how do I handle a failure as there is no possible function return and an exception is thrown?

Comment: I think there is more than one way to do it.  The IDs need not be stored in XML, depending on how elaborate you want to get.  For example, one could store the IDs in a key-value store, the "value" being a file path on the server side.  It might be more straightforward if the ID is simply in the XML, but either way could be made to work.  For the success/fail indication, is it not simply a matter of catching an exception on the server side and creating a graceful message based on that?  I may not be understanding your point on that one.